# Change Quality of ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView with the size of 70dp width and height. Its for my ListView and contains an image src of 800x800.

My Problem now is that this picture is so huge that it looks too **sharp** in my ImageView.
How can I prevent this ?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_albumart"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cd_800x800" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can play with your Bitmap. Rotate, compress ,convert other formats etc..
We decrease quality 100 to 25 in below code.

So this is code :

```
    Bitmap oldbitmap=Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)yourimageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    oldbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25,baos);
    Bitmap newbitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    yourimageview.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);
```

Comment: That really didnt helped my imageview is still very sharp. Yerim seni

Comment: Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 300, 300, true); This is decreasing resolution to 300x300 bizde çare tükenmez..

Comment: Thank you for your help but I think I have to blur the picture a bit because its still very sharp somehow. Eyvallah kardesim steamin varsa beni adlersen sevinirim : http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198227006600